# elasticsearch how to save user and it's tweets

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two tables in MySQL.
1st table is users and 2nd table is posts.
posts contain a user_id column.
can anyone explain data structure of my index?
I am using elasticsearch 7.5 version

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Would you be able to add more info for how you intend on using Elasticsearch?

Comment: I want a post with author details